# multiple Process.StartInfo.Arguments with textbox

Tags: c#

I tried to make simple GUI application to backup firebird database using gbak. The following is the process code

```
Process backingup = new Process();    
backingup.StartInfo.Filename = gbak;    
backingup.StartInfo.Arguments = "databaseBox.Text savedirBox.Text -user username.Text -pass pass.Text"    
backingup.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;    
backingup.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;    
backingup.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;    
backingup.Start();    
string backupoutput = backingup.StandardError.ReadToEnd();    
backingup.WaitForExit();    
ConsoleInfo.Text = backupoutput;
```

I cant get the arguments to pass correctly. The arguments I'm trying to input is

> "C:\DatabaseFile.GDB C:\BackupFile.GBK -user SYSDBA -pass masterkey"

Where:

- "C:\DatabaseFile.GDB" as the database.Text (TextBox)
- "C:\BackupFile.GBK" as the savedir.Text (TextBox)
- "SYSDBA" as the username.Text (TextBox)
- "masterkey" as the pass.Text (TextBox)

Answer (score 3):

You're literally using those strings rather than the values.

Try changing the arguments line to:

```
backingup.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} -user {2} -pass {3}", databaseBox.Text, savedirBox.Text, username.Text, pass.Text);
```

Note that you might need to add some double quotes to the format string as appropriate.

Comment: Hi Bridge, I tried your suggestion then got the following error;  Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Comment: @mikrotikamalatu Are you sure you copied and pasted it? The message would infer that you're missing one (or more) of the arguments passed to `string.Format`. In my example there are four placeholders for values, and four values passed - if there are a different number of placeholders in the format string to values passed afterwards, you'll get the error you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Bridge, Thanks it works now .. Thanks :) I just missed savedirBox.Text after databaseBox.Text.

Comment: @mikrotikamalatu Glad it helped, good luck with the rest of the project.